# Whats happend if websocket handshake timeout set 0

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I wanna get some insight about Handshake Timeout in websocket. Before that, I get this error from my websocket with `HandshakeTimeout` I set to `10 seconds`.

```
websocket: close 1006 (abnormal closure): unexpected EOF
```

I try to find how to solve this error, many groups say to increase the `HandshakeTimeout`.

But, my mind says different and wanna set config websocket like this:

```
ws := websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:   0,
    WriteBufferSize:  0,
    HandshakeTimeout: 0,
    CheckOrigin: func(r *nethttp.Request) bool {
        return true
    },
}
```

My question is. Is there any vulnerability issue or negative issue that comes up if I set `HandshakeTimeout` set to `0`?

I'm using [gorilla](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket) to setup websocket for in my code.

Comment: There is no timeout when the value is zero.  If there is no timeout, the resources associated with the connection (including the goroutine) can be held for an arbitrary amount of time.

Comment: Thanks Cerise, that explaining a lot. On your perspective this error `websocket: close 1006 (abnormal closure)` is normally? and what's value for `HandshakeTimeout` good to set?

Comment: @CeriseLimón Can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @suryatresna Have you solved the "close 1006" issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no timeout when the value is zero. If there is no timeout, the resources associated with the connection (including the goroutine) can be held for an arbitrary amount of time.